# Hybrid merge + insertion sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort, timsort

In the classical merge sort algorithm, one typically divides the input array until they have several single-element subarrays prior to merging the elements back together. But, it's well-known that you can modify this mergesort algorithm by splitting the arrays until you have, say, k subarrays, each of size n/k (n is the original length of the array). You can then use insertion sort to sort each one of those k subarrays and merge them using the merge subroutine.

Intuitively, I think that this should be better than just merge sort in some cases because insertion sort is fast on small arrays. But I want to figure out precisely when this hybrid algorithm is better than the regular merge sort algorithm. I don't think it would be better for small k because as k approaches 1, we'd just be using the insertion sort algorithm. I think there is some optimal ratio n/k, but I am not so sure how to find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For top down merge sort, size (n/k) = 32 seems to be ok. For bottom up, use 32 or 64 so that the number of merge passes is even.

Comment: The optimal ratio is configuration (machine, cpu, language, ...) dependent, so you would need to actually run tests with many samples, varying the ratio.